# freezing hover onclick after clicking a menu option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu.

```css
#menu {
  background: red;
}
.menu-option {} .menu-option:hover {
  background: maroon;
}
.menu-option:active {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu" align="center">
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(1)">Literary</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(2)">FilmFest</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(3)">Dance</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(4)">Music</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(5)">Fine Arts</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(6)">Quiz</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(7)">Dramatics</div>
</div>
```

Now what I want is, when I click any menu option the `background` of that specific `menu-option` should become `maroon` permanently till any other option is clicked while all others are `red`.

How do I achieve the same? CSS preferred.

Comment: You have some non semantic code there. You should not have multiple instances of an ID on your page. Use a class.

Comment: Wait, isn't the code already kinda what you want by changing the active color to maroon? What's the problem?

Comment: @Spokey the option after clicking should remain maroon, till any other option is clicked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A CSS solution would be to add tabindex to the elements in order for them to get focus, then on focus you set the color.

```css
#menu {
  background: red;
}
.menu-option:hover,
.menu-option:focus {
  background: maroon;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu" align="center">
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(1)" tabindex="-1">Literary</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(2)" tabindex="-1">FilmFest</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(3)" tabindex="-1">Dance</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(4)" tabindex="-1">Music</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(5)" tabindex="-1">Fine Arts</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(6)" tabindex="-1">Quiz</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(7)" tabindex="-1">Dramatics</div>
</div>
```

The problem here is that if the focus is lost the color is also gone, so instead some JS will be necessary. With JS you can just set the class

```js
$(function() { // execute after the elements are ready 
               // this is also a short form for $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu-option').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('maroon').siblings().removeClass('maroon');
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  background: red;
}
.menu-option:hover,
.menu-option.maroon {
  background: maroon;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" align="center">
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(1)">Literary</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(2)">FilmFest</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(3)">Dance</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(4)">Music</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(5)">Fine Arts</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(6)">Quiz</div>
  <div class="menu-option" align="center" onclick="showgenre(7)">Dramatics</div>
</div>
```

In order for the script to execute correctly the elements must first be loaded.    This means you may put the script in the head of the document but then you have to set a ready handler to wait for the elements. Alternatively you may put it after the elements are loaded near the end of body.

Comment: @CodeGirl you tagged jQuery so I'm assuming you have the plugin included? Do you get errors in your console? Do you still use IDs instead of classes in your code?

Comment: I have included jQuery library, and i am now using "class", and i am not getting any errors.

Comment: If you are putting this script in head you have to wrap it in a ready handler, I'll update my answer with that. Else this script needs to be near the end of body.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks.

Comment: can you also mention in the answer about order of execution with the position of script in the page.

Comment: Sure, I added the info. You should also consider moving the logic from `showgenre()` in the jQuery click handler and avoid inline ones.